# Using HTML links within translatable string

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, security, translation

What harm could happen if I didn't use the `wp_kses` function when using HTML links within translatable string?
I know what this function do but what I don't understand is why and when should I implement this function? Specially with translatable strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It basically depends on who is doing the translation and how trusted can he be as if you will not filter things out the translator can add JS code, still cookies and whatever.

In most of the places translation is done you will have in any case  a call to `esc_html` or `esc_attr` which will mitigate the problem, but obviously if you need an actual link, you can not use those functions. The use of `wp_kses` just makes sure there are no surprises in the translation.

For example, there is nothing that prevent a translator from translating `__('Hi there`) into `Hi there <script>alert('evil laugh')</script>`. translations are never verified to not include such type of things when they are submitted by translators, and while the example is easy to catch, it might be possible to do more complex things that are harder to spot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. and this is axactly what I need to know.. what kind of surprise that could happen.. I need a before and after example if it is possible please

Comment: there could be a JS in the translation

Comment: Please be patient and consider I am a beginner.. I need a low low level discussion... how the translator would add those harmful codes? And what do you mean by the translator ? A person or translation tools like poedit

Comment: I mean the person doing the translation, and there is nothing comlex he will just add that JS code the same way he uses poedit to translate all strings

Comment: Ahaaa..so when he translate he may inject codes with the translation itself so when loading the theme/plugin the code runs and do staff.isn't it?

Comment: yes, exactly...